# Split the text file in python

Tags: python, text

I have a text file with some records having similar fields.

```
    name:
    Class:
    Subject:
    name:
    Class:
    Subject:
```

As above mentioned this file can have any number of records and I want to separate each record with respective fields.
Following is how far I could reach in order to pursue this problem.

```
    def counter(file_path):
       count = 0
       file_to_read = open(file_path)
       text_to_read = file_to_read.readlines()
       file_to_read.close()
       for line in text_to_read:
           if line.find('name') != -1:
              count = count + 1
       return count
```

This way i can count the no. of records present in the file and now I'm finding it difficult to split the whole text file in segments equal to no. of records.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does all records take 3 lines ?

Comment: Try thinking some more. You have a long way to go before you accomplish what you want.

Comment: You said, that some records have similar fields. Does it mean that your file doesn't have strict structure, i.e. some of the records doesn't have one or both fields 'Class' and 'Subject', while other records have additional fields? And also, what do you mean by 'split the whole text file in segments equal to no. of records.' - do you need list of lists of strings or something else?

Comment: Let me rephrase my words. All the records have same fields and they are of three lines. It can happen that one of the field is left empty but still it will be mentioned in text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def records(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as f:
        chunk = []
        for line in f:
            if 'name' in line:
                if chunk:
                    yield chunk
                chunk = [line]
            else:
                chunk.append(line)
        if chunk:
            yield chunk

for record in records('data.txt'):
    print '--------'
    print ''.join(record)
```

prints

```
--------
    name:
    Class:
    Subject:

--------
    name:
    Class:
    Subject:
```