# Python: split a large text file by many headers

Tags: python, file, text, split, header

I have a large text file, which looks like this:

```
lat lon altitude pressure
3 lines data group bsas
2.3 4.5 45.0 875
5.6 6.5 46.2 676
3.4 3.4 48.2 565
6 lines data group sdad
3.4 4.5 56.1 535
5.6 6.5 46.2 676    
3.4 4.5 56.1 535
2.3 4.5 45.0 875
5.6 6.5 46.2 676
3.4 3.4 48.2 565
50 lines data group asdasd
5.5 6.6 44.5 343
...
3.7 8.4 56.5 456
... and so on
```

I want to split whole text file to separate data group, each data group will be stored in a 2d array. Till now I have tried 2 ways to do that.

The first way is going through each line and get data as follows:

```
# define an object class called Wave here
# each object has 4 attributes: lat, lon, altitude, pressure
wave_list = []
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    next(f) # skip the header
    wave = Wave()
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if 'data' in line:
            if wave is not empty:
                wave_list.append(wave)
            wave = Wave()
        else:
            wave.lat.append(line.split()[0])
            wave.lon.append(line.split()[1])
            wave.altitude.append(line.split()[2])
            wave.pressure.append(line.split()[3])
        wave_list.append(wave)
return wave_list
```

The second approach is using numpy loadtext:

```
f = open(filename, 'r')
txt = f.read()
# split by "data", remove the first element
raw_chunks = txt.split("data")[1:]
# define a new list to store results
wave_list = []
# go through each chunk
for rc in raw_chunks:
    # find the fisrt index of "\n"
    first_id = rc.find("\n")
    # find the last index of "\n"
    last_id = rc.rfind("\n")
    # temporary chunk
    temp_chunk = rc[first_id:last_id]
    # load data using loadtxt
    data = np.loadtxt(StringIO(temp_chunk)          
    wave = Wave()
    wave.lat = data.T[0]
    wave.lon = data.T[1]
    wave.altitude = data.T[2]
    wave.pressure = data.T[3]
    wave_list.append(wave)
return wave_list
```

However, both approaches are quite slow. I have a look at pandas documentation but cannot find the way to avoid the headers in the middle of the file. I also have a look at different questions for examples:

[Splitting a file based on text in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791024/splitting-a-file-based-on-text-in-python)

[Split the text file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13622326/split-the-text-file-in-python)

[How to split and parse a big text file in python in a memory-efficient way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602848/how-to-split-and-parse-a-big-text-file-in-python-in-a-memory-efficient-way?rq=1)

but none of them solves my problem. Is there any faster way to read this kind of text file. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what data do you want to split on?

Comment: @Padraic the data shown as an example above. Or what do you mean? Sorry I don't really understand

Comment: yes, do you want to split wherever there is text?

Comment: @Padraic: I want to split by the line, which contains the word "data"

Comment: `re.split(".*data.*",f.read())` will split into sections

Comment: @Padraic but does require loading into RAM all at once... it's possible iteratively

Comment: @JonClements, but which is faster?

Comment: @Padraic and Jon is there anyway to use pandas (or similar module) to split into sections and at the same time load each section into data frame? If not, then load data by going though each line (as my 1st suggestion), or split into sections and then get data from each section (as your suggestions) is faster, from your experience? Thanks both of you a lot!

Comment: how big is your data file?

Comment: @Padraic: each file is about 50 Mb and for one run I will need to load about 720 files

Comment: that is almost 40 gig, how will that work memory wise?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I don't have any really good idea. First I load data of all 720 files into very huge lists --> arrays and do the calculations in the end with these arrays. But at that moment my computer is really slow and it dies sometimes. So I decided to load every 240 files, do calculations, save results as temp_result1 via pickle and in the end combine temp_result1, temp_result2, temp_result3. Any smarter suggestion?

Comment: @Jon Clements and Padraic Cunningham by the way I have tested 2 ways of splitting file. The method suggested by Jon Clements is about 3 times faster than Padraic Cunningham's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for lines that start with `<number> lines data group <something>`, store the group (`<something>`) and the number of lines to read (`<number>`), then when it matches, store the *n* following of lines to that *group*, eg:

Given the following code:

```
from itertools import islice
from collections import defaultdict
import re

data = defaultdict(list) 
with open(filename) as fin:
    header = next(fin, '').split()
    for line in fin:
        m = re.match(r'(\d+) lines.*(\b\w+)$', line)
        if m:
            data[m.group(2)].extend(islice(fin, int(m.group(1))))
```

Given input of:

```
lat lon altitude pressure
3 lines data group bsas
2.3 4.5 45.0 875
5.6 6.5 46.2 676
3.4 3.4 48.2 565
6 lines data group sdad
3.4 4.5 56.1 535
5.6 6.5 46.2 676    
3.4 4.5 56.1 535
2.3 4.5 45.0 875
5.6 6.5 46.2 676
3.4 3.4 48.2 565
```

Gives you `data` as:

```
{'bsas': ['2.3 4.5 45.0 875\n', '5.6 6.5 46.2 676\n', '3.4 3.4 48.2 565\n'],
 'sdad': ['3.4 4.5 56.1 535\n',
          '5.6 6.5 46.2 676    \n',
          '3.4 4.5 56.1 535\n',
          '2.3 4.5 45.0 875\n',
          '5.6 6.5 46.2 676\n',
          '3.4 3.4 48.2 565\n']}
```

Further to your comments, if the "group" is insignificant, then:

```
data = []
with open(filename) as fin:
    header = next(fin, '').split()
    for line in fin:
        m = re.match(r'(\d+) lines.*(\b\w+)$', line)
        if m:
            data.append(list(islice(fin, int(m.group(1)))))
```

Comment: Actually the lines with "lines data group" contain an undefined number of whitespace in front of the number. How can I overcome this? should I use `re.search` instead of `re.match` or should I used `line.lstrip()`? which one is faster?

Comment: @ Jon Clements: oh I found out that adding `\s*` is probably the best way to ignore these whitespaces. Now if I want to store these data groups in a list or array, not in a dictionary, how can I do that? The reason is that, the string following `"data group"` is arbitrary and could be the same in some lines, so I don't want it to be the key of a dictionary. Thank you

Comment: @hoangtran So if you had `1 data group a\nblah\n1 data group a\nblah2\n` then you want two lists, not one list containing [`blah', 'blah2']` as this approach gives you?

Comment: @ Jon Clements: No, I want one list, or one array, but not a dictionary. Because the words you chose for being keywords of the dictionary are `'blah', 'blah2', ..` but in reality they can be repeated sometimes, e.g. `'blah', 'blah', 'blah3', 'blah2', 'blah3', 'blah3'..`

Comment: @hoangtran so if your data had 20 `bsas` with *n* many rows, you want a list containing 20 different lists?

Comment: Yes, I do. Sorry I didn't understand your comment above.

Comment: @hoangtran updated... that way, you'll only receive a list of lists

Comment: @hoangtran you'd probably also be better off depending what you're trying to do, wrapping it in a function and `yeild`ing the `list(islice(...))` result then worry about it from outside...to take the results in chunks, then aggregate your DF's

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am a bit concerned that `list(is lice(...))` can takes quite a long time ..

Comment: @hoangtran it'll take as long as it will take to read *n* many lines from a file - that's all that `.extend` is doing - the `islice` returns an iterable like object, all you're doing is materialising it to a new list instead of extending an existing list (as per my previous example)

Comment: @hoangtran I'll note that this question is now getting out of the "How do I do what I asked?" category and feature creeping into "How do I manage the results to do X?"? :p So - possibly best as another question, unless anything's unclear about this answer that doesn't achieve what you asked?